# Android custom listView array adapter doesn't work at first time

Tags: android, listview, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a custom `arrayAdapter` for `listView`. It doesn't show data according to firebase values(shows default data) when app is installed for the first time. But if I clear app from cache/recents, everything works fine after that.

Which means adapter works fine in second run after clearing cache/recents.

What am I doing wrong?

I have already applied `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` but nothing happens.

**Everything works fine after clearing recents/cache.**

Thanks

below is the code from my adapter file

========================================================================

```
public class SaveFilteredContactsDetailsListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<SaveFilteredContactDetails> implements View.OnClickListener{

    Context mContext;

    public SaveFilteredContactsDetailsListAdapter(ArrayList<SaveFilteredContactDetails> data, Context context) {
        super(context, R.layout.textforcontacts, data);
        this.dataSet = data;
        this.mContext=context;
    }


    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        SaveFilteredContactDetails dataModel = getItem(position);

        ViewHolder viewHolder; 

        final View result;

        if (convertView == null) {

            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.textforcontacts, parent, false);
           result=convertView;

            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);




            /////firebase value checks////////
            firebaseInitializations();
            mDatabaseRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {

                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    for(DataSnapshot ds:dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                        RequestManager requestManager =new RequestManager();


                        ///////////check if any received request and waiting for responses, make response view available?/////////
                        if(ds.child("requests")
                         .child(UserID)
                         .hasChild(dataModel.get_idFromFirebase()))
                        {
                            requestManager.setReqStatus(ds.child("requests")
                                                      .child(UserID)
                                                      .child(dataModel.get_idFromFirebase())
                                                      .getValue(RequestManager.class)
                                                      .getReqStatus());
                            String tempStatus = requestManager.getReqStatus();

                            //Toast.makeText(mContext, tempStatus, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            if(tempStatus.equals("received")) {
                            viewHolder.pendingResponse.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            viewHolder.trackLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            viewHolder.unBlockedResponse.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        }
                        if(tempStatus.equals("cancel"))
                        {
                            viewHolder.pendingResponse.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            viewHolder.trackLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            viewHolder.unBlockedResponse.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        }
                        if(tempStatus.equals("released"))
                        {
                            viewHolder.pendingResponse.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            viewHolder.trackLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            viewHolder.unBlockedResponse.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        }
                        if(tempStatus.equals("blocked"))
                        {
                            viewHolder.pendingResponse.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            viewHolder.trackLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            viewHolder.unBlockedResponse.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        }
                        if(tempStatus.equals("unblocked"))
                        {
                            viewHolder.pendingResponse.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            viewHolder.trackLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            viewHolder.unBlockedResponse.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        }
                        if(tempStatus.equals("accepted"))
                        {
                            viewHolder.pendingResponse.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            viewHolder.trackLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            viewHolder.unBlockedResponse.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        }
                    }

                    ///////////////check if we sent request to current user and whats the status?////////////////
                    if(ds.child("requests")
                         .child(dataModel.get_idFromFirebase())
                         .hasChild(UserID))
                    {
                        requestManager.setReqStatus(ds.child("requests")
                                                      .child(dataModel.get_idFromFirebase())
                                                      .child(UserID)
                                                      .getValue(RequestManager.class)
                                                      .getReqStatus());
                        String tempStatus = requestManager.getReqStatus();

                        //Toast.makeText(mContext, tempStatus, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        if(tempStatus.equals("received"))
                        {
                            viewHolder.releaseRequests.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            viewHolder.pendingRequests.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            viewHolder.sendRequests.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            viewHolder.blockedResponse.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                        }
                        if(tempStatus.equals("accepted"))
                        {
                            viewHolder.pendingRequests.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            viewHolder.sendRequests.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            viewHolder.releaseRequests.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            viewHolder.blockedResponse.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                        }
                        if(tempStatus.equals("rejected"))
                        {
                            viewHolder.releaseRequests.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            viewHolder.pendingRequests.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            viewHolder.sendRequests.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            viewHolder.blockedResponse.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        }
                        if(tempStatus.equals("blocked"))
                        {
                            viewHolder.releaseRequests.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            viewHolder.pendingRequests.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            viewHolder.sendRequests.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            viewHolder.blockedResponse.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        }
                        if(tempStatus.equals("unblocked"))
                        {
                            viewHolder.releaseRequests.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            viewHolder.pendingRequests.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            viewHolder.sendRequests.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            viewHolder.blockedResponse.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        }
                    }

                    ///////////////check online offline status?////////////////
                    if(ds.child("onOffStatus")
                         .hasChild(dataModel.get_idFromFirebase()))
                    {
                        requestManager.setOnlineOfflineStatus(ds.child("onOffStatus")
                                                                .child(dataModel.get_idFromFirebase())
                                                                .getValue(RequestManager.class)
                                                                .isOnlineOfflineStatus());
                        if(requestManager.isOnlineOfflineStatus())
                            viewHolder.onOffStatusDot.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        else
                            viewHolder.onOffStatusDot.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            }
        });
    } else {
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        result=convertView;
    }
```

=========================================================================

Am i coding wrong?

Comment: We'll need to see your code to able to help

Comment: Thanks for response. please check the code in edited post.

Comment: /////firebase value checks////////  after this line you have written a code right, that has to be written after the else statement

Comment: I tried that, but it doesn't work.. it also works even after starting some other firebase activity.
but not working after installing app or first time

Comment: what might be the possible reason? why firebase code is not working at first install :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dear @karthik vishnu kumar,
Thanks for that correction in code.

The solution was, in previous activity I coded for firebase instance to go offline onStop(). So I needed to remove it from the code.

**What I learnt is, never ever go offline with firebase instance if it will be used in next activity**